# Is there a Symfony bundle that can be used to implement oAuth2 server that works with Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0

I need to implement oAuth2 server in Symfony 3.

Is there a bundle for Symfony 3 that already does that?

In other words what is a recommended bundle to use to implement oAuth server in Symfony 3?

Answer (score 0):

i guess this would help

as a server : 
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle

as a client : 
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

Comment: afaik the FOS bundle does not work with Symfony 3. But a few years ago I implemented a server with it on Symfony 2.3 and it worked like a charm.

Comment: yea it doesnt work no more in symfony 3.x.x  . thanks

Answer (score -1):

found a few bundles on internet:

- https://github.com/authbucket/oauth2-symfony-bundle
- https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle
- https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle

To find these results please go to http://google.com and type "symfony3 oauth bundle" - this helps me very often.

Comment: Link only answers are always frowned upon.  And in this case in particular, since the original poster clearly has no idea how to use the internet, I'm not really sure how they can help.

Comment: Edited my answer, maybe now it will help a bit more

Comment: Maybe the original question was just badly phrased. Maybe the user is not just looking for links but for real recommendations from users that have actually implemented an oAuth2 server in Symfony 3 (they would probably not post links to oauth client bundles)

Comment: Why are you being such a smart asses? Do you really think I did not go to google first? First of all you haven't even read the question and think about it. You just want to be a smart ass. I have asked nicely that I need to implement oAuth Server and you are giving me links to bundles that implement only client side. I know for both https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle and https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle and with them I can only implement a client as far as I can tell but not oAuth server where I can create clients with client id and client secret.

Comment: And I honestly did not found https://github.com/authbucket/oauth2-symfony-bundle on google which I will look and investigate now.